# Colors in googleVis gvisScatterChart

Tags: r, googlevis

I'm having a problem getting the google charts API in R to properly plot colors in a scatter plot.

```
library("googleVis")
df=data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(2,3,4))
opts = list(pointSize = 1, colors="['red', 'black', 'blue']")
Sc <- gvisScatterChart(df, options=opts)
plot(Sc)
```

All of the dots are red.

Much appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue myself & figured out how to fix it - since documentation/discussion on this topic is sparse, posting here for posterity.

In this example, looks like you have three points and want each to be a different color (red, black, blue respectively), and your dataframe takes the form of X,Y scatterplot (2 columns).  **If you want to group scatterplot points, each group needs its own Y column**.

Your dataframe needs to look like this, where the first column is understood as X, and the other columns are understood as Y values, each representing its own color:

```
df=data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(2,NA,NA), x3=c(NA,3,NA), x4=c(NA,NA,4));
```

Full code now show three different colored points (below).  Note: the *colors* option are the colors of the *groups*, not the individual points. You have three points and three groups, so this example doesn't clearly show that.

```
df=data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3), x2=c(2,NA,NA), x3=c(NA,3,NA), x4=c(NA,NA,4));
opts = list(pointSize = 15, legend='none', colors="['red', 'black', 'blue']");
Sc <- gvisScatterChart(df, options=opts);
plot(Sc);
```

You're essentially breaking your Y values into different columns based on some grouping. This caveat is not entirely straight-forward, but here's how I broke an X,Y scatterplot dataframe into multiple group columns, given a third column "GROUP" which encodes a numerical membership ID for each row (ex. 1 - 10):

```
# Original X,Y dataframe
colnames(df) <- c("X","Y","GROUP");
# Create an n-column dataframe based on number of groups
Y_cols <- t(data.frame(x=rep(x=NA, times=length(unique(df$GROUP)))));
# Bind n-groups new columns to original dataframe
df_viz <- suppressWarnings(cbind(df, Y_cols));
# Copy the Y value to the appropriate column based on group ID
for(r in 1:nrow(df_viz)) df_viz[r,as.character(df_viz[r,"GROUP"])] <- df_viz[r,"Y"];
# Drop original Y and GROUP columns
df_viz <- df_viz[,-(2:3)];
```

And then your *colors* option in *gvisScatterChart* would look something like, which uses RColorBrewer to generate a dynamic color palette based on the number of distinct groups:

```
colors=paste("['",paste(brewer.pal(max(df$GROUPS),"Paired"), collapse = "\',\'"),"']", sep="")
```

There's probably more concise way to achieving this, but that's basically the gist of it.

Hope this helps!